# merge sort merge run time anaylsis

Tags: merge, runtime

I have some confusion of the run time analysis of the merge function in merge sort.

```
Merg(A,p,q,r)
1 n1=q-p+1
2 n2=r-q
3 let L[1..n1+1] and R[1..n2+1] be new arrays
4 for i=1 to n1
5     L[i] = A[p+i-1]
6 for j =1 to n2
7    R[j] = A[q+j]
8  L[n1+1] = infinity
9 R[n2+1] = infinity
10 i =0
11 j=0
12 for k=p to r
13   if L[i]<=R[j]
14       A[k]=L[i]
15       i=i+1
16    else A[k] = R[j]
17       j=j+1
```

In my book it says the following: to see that the merge procedure runs in O(n) time, where n=r-p+1, observe that each of lines 1-3 and 8-11 takes constant time, the for loops of lines 4-7 take O(n1+n2) = O(n)time, and there are n iterations of the for oop of lines 12-17, each of which takes constant time

My question is why do lines 12-17 take constant time per iteration and not affect the run time but
lines 4-7 don't take constant time. to me, it seems like both loops are doing the same thing. can someone help clarify this for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's confusingly written. Both loops (4-7 and 12-17) have the same length (n) and the inside of both loops are constant time (no nested loops). So they're each O(n), for a total of O(n) for the whole routine.

Regarding Jerry's answer, lines 4-7 matter because they're still O(n). If you could magically remove lines 12-17 you'd still have an O(n) routine.

Comment: OH WOW. im dumb lol. for some reason i was thinking of them as being nested, which would make it O(n^2) but it would really be 2n which is just O(n). the books explanation is definitely not written in the best way, but i understand it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Lines 1 through 9 are just splitting the input (`A`) into two pieces (`L` and `R`). Lines 10 and 11 are doing a bit of initializing to get ready for merging. The merge itself is from lines 12-17.

IOW, everything before line 12 (or *arguably* 10, not that it really matters) is irrelevant to analyzing the *merge* because none of it is really part of the merge at all.

Edit: Ultimately, however, a single iteration from 1 to 27 is linear: in lines 4-7, you walk exactly once through the input array, assigning each input exactly once to either L or R. In lines 12-27, you then walk through those two pieces, and copy them back to the original input. Ignoring a few other minor details like initializing `i` and `j`, the total number of operations is exactly 2N. For big-O notation, constant factors are ignored, so it's O(N).

Comment: well, thats what i would assume too, but the book says that the O(n) run time comes from lines 4-7, not lines 12-27